# Segmentation fault:11 error while implementing Doubly Linked List Data Structure

Tags: c, data-structures

While implementing this Doubly Linked list Data Structure, I am getting Segmentation fault:11 error.

I have posted my code in the form of image below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
struct node* prev ; 
int data ; 
struct node* next ; 
}; 
struct node* first=NULL ; 
void create(int[],int);›
void display(struct node*);
int  main()
{
int A[]={ }; 
int cap ; 

printf("Enter how many elements do you want to insert in the Linked 
List :\n");
scanf("%d",&cap); 

printf("Enter the elements that you want to insert in the Linked List 
in the form of a Array Stream :\n");

for(int i=0 ; i<cap ; i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&A[i]);
}

create(A,cap); 
display(first);

}



void create(int A[],int n)
{
struct node* t ;                                

struct node* last ; 

first=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
first->data=A[0] ; 
first->prev=NULL ; 
first->next=NULL ; 
last=first ; 

for(int i=1 ; i<n ; i++)
{
t=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
t->data=A[i]; 
t->prev=last ; 
t->next=NULL ; 
last->next=t ; 
last=t ; 


}


}

void display(struct node* p ) 
{  
printf("\n");
printf("The Elements that are present in the Linked List are :\n");
while(p!=NULL)
{
    printf("%d-->",p->data);
    p=p->next ; 
}
```

}

While I am trying to run the program and suppose for instance I am inserting 2-3 elements in the linked list in the form of array, then it is working fine but when I try to insert more than 3 elements it gives me Segmentation fault :11 error

Comment: Don't post images. Post code

Comment: @deprirscher I have posted the code in the form of image . Please have a look

Comment: No, post code as text so we can see it here and maybe copy it to an editor and try it out

Comment: I tried posting the code in the form of text but Stackoverflow isnt allowing me to enter it in the form of text .

Comment: There is a way to post code as text: four spaces at least on every line

Comment: Yes it does. Just copy it from your editor and paste it into the textarea where you entered your question

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Use the `gdb` debugger and `valgrind`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Now i have posted the code in the form of text . Please have a look

Comment: Well, you create an empty array with `int A[]={ };` and then attempt to read into it with `scanf("%d",&A[i]);`. What did you expect to happen? Memory isn't allocated magically, and you know it because you're using `malloc` later on in your code.

Comment: Then , what should i do to dynamically ask for elements from the user and then insert in the doubly linked list . Please tell me the changes which i need to incorporate

Comment: @ForceBru What are the Changes that i need to incorporate in my Code ?

Comment: @DeepanshuArora, you need to at least allocate the memory for this array

Comment: Ask capacity first and then create your array `A` with the correct size.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare your integer array after getting the size of it from the user.

```
printf("Enter how many elements do you want to insert in the Linked 
List :\n");
scanf("%d",&cap); 

int A[cap];

printf("Enter the elements that you want to insert in the Linked List 
in the form of a Array Stream :\n");

for(int i=0 ; i<cap ; i++)
{
  scanf("%d",&A[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out !!